# Fees for depositing US social security check

Tags: banking, retirement, check

My bank charges a significant fee for deposits of US Social Security checks. Is this generally a paid service or I should explore other banks and get lower fees?

Comment: Change banks. There should never be a fee gor depositing a check written to you into your own account.

Comment: c/gor/for/ in previous comment, of course.

Comment: Is there something we are missing? Are you out of the country? Have you avoided the requirement to switch to direct deposit only?

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. OPS is not asking for a specific bank, just if this type of fee is customary.

Comment: Are you depositing _your_ Social Security check into _your_ account, or did Grandma endorse her Socal Security check over to you and you are now trying to deposit it in your checking account? (Whether you gave Grandma the cash equivalent or not is not relevant). I can imagine the bank being suspicious and demanding a fee in the latter case to cover the increased risk of cashing (or trying to collect) what _might_ turn out to be a stolen Social Security check. But, if it is your own check, why not ask the Social Security Administration to deposit it via ACH directly into your own account?

Answer (score 2):

Banks may choose to charge whatever they want for whatever services they offer (at least, within legal limits), because they are a business. It's unusual for a bank to charge a service fee for cashing a check, but not impossible. As a commenter said, you should consider shopping around for a new bank. Most banks will give you literature regarding their fees upfront if you ask.